# get dynamically updated stats monthly rails

Tags: ruby, datetime, ruby-on-rails-4

I have Rails4 application.

```
class Developer 
has_many :client_applications

class ClientApplication 
belongs_to :developer
```

Among `ClientApplication's` attributes there is `cost`.

What I can do is to get developer's total earning by:

```
def total_earning
  self.client_applications.where(status: "Closed").map{|c| c.cost}.inject(&:+).to_i
end
```

What I want is to have a table of statistics. Table should have `month` column and `total_earning` column with corresponding to this `month` value.

I only want to get columns where `total_earning` is nonzero value (so that if developer earned $0 in February, this month is not present in table).

I can hardcode the month into `total_earning` method's query (which is dumb and one-off way), I would like to know if there (I am sure there is) a way to do it nice and smooth.

Would appreciated for any hints!

Comment: You want to store aggregated data in your database as a way to speed things up?

Comment: The original aim is to let admin see the developers earnings easy and fast. He can always go to developers profile, look for his projects, see it's dates and statuses, select those which where closed in current month (if any) and calculate money to pay developer. But when there are a lot of devs - it becomes extremely error prone and inefficient

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the solution I've come up with is following(ActiveAdmin table):

```
      table do
        Hash[*developer.client_applications.load.where(status: "Closed").group_by{|a| [a.updated_at.month, a.updated_at.year]}.map{|a,b| ["#{Date::MONTHNAMES[a[0]]} #{a[1]}", b.map(&:cost).map(&:to_i).inject(&:+)]}.reject{|entry| entry[1] == [0, nil]}.flatten].each_pair do |k, v|
          tr do
            td k
            td number_to_currency(v, unit: "$")
          end
        end
      end
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do a callback each time a `ClientApplication` record is saved to update your stats table like this:

```
class Developer 
has_many :client_applications
```

Add this:

```
class ClientApplication 
belongs_to :developer
after_save :update_statistics

def update_statistics
  if self.status == "Closed"
    stats = Statistic.find_or_create_by(developer: self.developer, month: self.created_at)
    stats.total_earning += self.cost
    stats.save
  end 
end

class Statisitc
has_many :developers
has_many :client_applications
```

Comment: hey! thanks a lot for the proposition! I've solved this in a bit different way